# Send an Outlook email from Excel putting the last row range text in the body message

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I would like to send an email from my Excel spreadsheet  with a small message into the body containing the last row range from column A to column G.

I've tried to add my last row range to the following code without success.

Can you help?

```
Sub Mail_LastRowRange_Outlook()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

strbody = "Thanks for your help" & '**I Would like to insert_
           my last row range from column A to G in here**

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Looking for a solution"
    .Body = strbody
    .Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
    .Send   
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub test1()
  Dim lastRow As Long
  'get last row from column A of worksheet with 'codename' Sheet1
  lastRow = getLastRow(Sheet1, 1)

  Dim r As Range
  Set r = Sheet1.Range("A" & lastRow & ":G" & lastRow)

  Dim str As String
  'Join the cell texts with a space - lazy coding...
  str = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(r.Value2)), " ")

  MsgBox str
End Sub


Public Function getLastRow(ws As Worksheet, Optional col As Long) As Long
  Dim arr As Variant

  If col > 0 Then
        arr = Intersect(ws.UsedRange, ws.Columns(col)).Value2
  Else
        arr = ws.UsedRange.Value2
  End If

  Dim i As Long, j As Long
  For i = UBound(arr) To 1 Step -1
        For j = UBound(arr, 2) To 1 Step -1
              If Len(arr(i, j)) > 0 Then
                    getLastRow = i + ws.UsedRange.Row - 1
                    Exit Function
              End If
        Next j
  Next i
End Function
```

The function above is **THE** most robust function to get the last row of actual data value in a worksheet/column. Everything else is vulnerable including `Range.Find("*", , , , , xlPrevious)` which is vulnerable to activeCell in filtered ListObject

The function below is susceptible to a couple things like filtered rows, last row having data, etc etc.

```
Public Function getLastRow2(ws As Worksheet, col As Long) As Long
    getLastRow2 = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

Comment: Hi MacroMarc, please how can I put Sub test1() in the body mail?

Comment: Thanks for all your wonderful support. It works ok now. In column A I have got Date figure that appear in email in number form. I will try to sort it out. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This should work, as long as there are no blank cells in column A from cell A1 through the last row with data in column A.  Replace the line that you have "strbody = ...." with all of this.

```
Cells(1,1).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select

Dim s As String
s = ActiveCell.Value     'A
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
s = s & ActiveCell.Value 'B
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
s = s & ActiveCell.Value 'C
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
s = s & ActiveCell.Value 'D
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
s = s & ActiveCell.Value 'E
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
s = s & ActiveCell.Value 'F
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
s = s & ActiveCell.Value 'G

strbody = "Thanks for your help" & s
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sometimes anyway there are some empty cells in my spreadsheet. Do you think could it be possible to get a solution to my case?

Comment: no need for selecting cells. Just hook onto the range object and work with it.. Also for last row, better to go from bottom and use xlUp like: `Cells(sheet1.rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)`. Then get the range across to column G by Offset

Comment: Start at a column you know won't be blank.  Or, put in a dummy column and key off of that to find the end.

Comment: Totally agree with MacroMarc on how to get the last row.....wish I had thought of that before....

Comment: Hi MacroMarc, sorry to be a dummy, can you put on code what you said 6min ago so I can understand better? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

determine the specific row, and create a range object and iterate over it, e.g.:

```
    Dim rng As range
    Dim item As range
    Dim row As Long

    Set rng = range(Cells(row, 1), Cells(row, 7))

    For Each item In rng
        strBody = strBody & " " & item
    Next item
```

Comment: Sorry about my question. Is the specific row corresponding to lastrow?

Comment: Yes, but you have to find the last row. You can use the suggested method of MacroMarc in the answer above, and store the result in a new range object and query the row value by range.row

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply

Comment: If your sheet is not sheet1, in the method of MacroMarc, you can use `Sheets("insert_name_of_the_sheet")` instead.